# Sql Azure/Server AS TIME ZONE

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I tried to do the following

```
(SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE  'Central European Standard Time')
```

However i get something like this

2016-10-17 16:35:25.260 +02:00

which is the UTC time followed by that +02:00 thing.( no clue what this is )

How should i convert this to CET which should be **18**:35:25.2560

Central European Summer Time.

Comment: +02:00 indicates the time is offset from UTC by +2 hours, as it is for CEST at the moment.

Comment: [This feature may not be completely ready](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/07/sql-plan/at-time-zone). This is the smallest statement I could figure out to get what you want, and I have to believe it should be simpler than this: `SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, SYSUTCDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE  N'Central European Standard Time'), -DATEPART(TZ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())), 0);`

Comment: For the approach I used *before* AT TIME ZONE : [Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3173/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server---part-1/), [Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3174/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server---part-2/), [Part 3](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3175/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server---part-3/).

Comment: `AT TIME ZONE`  applied to datetime do not change the value, just converts it to datetimeoffset. You should apply`AT TIME ZONE`   to to datetimeoffset to change the value.  So in your case something like `(GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE  '+00:00') AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'`

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled over the same problem you have.
The following will work!

```
SELECT (GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'
```